# Как забрать данные с файла: достать json информацию?

Tags: json, php, файлы

Добрый вечер. Возникла трудность: как забрать данные с файла, если он имеет данные содержимое

```
24Х{"clientVersion": "World of Warplanes 1.3.1 ", "playerName": "InnoT20", "mapDisplayName": "02_el_hallouf", "dateTime": "07.05.2014 22:25:48", "mapName": "02_el_hallouf", "gameplayID": 6, "playerVehicle": "ki-33"}TњxШ е¶
```

и т.д.
интересует как достать `json` информацию
пробовал делать `var_dump`
пишет NULL
я в тупике, как быть?

Comment: если там гарантированно лежит объект, то обрезать слева от первой скобки и справа от последней.

Comment: самолёт, карта и т.п. может быть разными и иметь разное кол-во символом

Comment: @innot сейчас наш диалог выглядит так:

- Мешок с сахаром стоит слева от варенья и справа от метода
- Но он же может быть разной ширины!

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы спарсить json строку в PHP есть функция json_decode($vasha_json_stroka) ;

```
$json = '{var : 1, var2 : "asd"}' ;
$arr = json_decode($json) ;
var_dump($arr) ;
```

Выведет следующее

```
array(
   var => 1,
   var2 => asd
) ;
```